# how do I decrease a value of a variable in every if statement

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am creating rock, paper, scissor in python. I have created two variables called comp_life and life. If I or the computer will lose, it will decrease and store the value the two variables

I used life = life - 1 in every if statement I lose and comp = comp - 1 in every statement I won.
I expected that the value will be stored and will be applied in every if statement. But I think the value is stored in only that if statement, not other if statement.

```
import random

print ("welcome. I am bob the AI.\nWe will play rock paper scissors. This is how we play rock paper           scissors\nRock beat scissors\nScissors beat paper\nPaper beat paper rock\n")
print ("you and bob have three lives if you lose all lives the game will be over, if computer lose all lives you will win \n\n")
while True:
    def rock_paper_scissors():
        life = 3
        comp_life = 3
        print("1 = rock\n2 = paper\n3 =scissors\nEnter")
        user_choice = int(input("1, 2, 3\n"))
        if user_choice == 1:
            name = "rock"
        elif user_choice == 2:
            name = "paper"
        elif user_choice == 3:
            name = "scissors"
        if user_choice > 3 or user_choice < 1:
            print("Invalid choice")
            rock_paper_scissors()
        print("You choosed ", name)
        print("Bob's turn")
        computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
        if user_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 2:
            print("You lose")
            life = life - 1
            print("you lost a life")
            print("bob choosed paper")
            print("you now have ", life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 2 and computer_choice == 1:
            print("You win")
            comp_life = comp_life - 1
            print("computer lost a life")
            print("bob choosed rock")
            print("computer now have ", comp_life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 1:
            print("Draw")
        elif user_choice == 2 and computer_choice == 2:
            print("Draw")
        elif user_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 3:
            print("You win")
            comp_life = comp_life - 1
            print("computer lost a life")
            print("bob choosed scissors")
            print("computer now have ", comp_life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 2 and computer_choice == 3:
            print("You lose")
            life = life - 1
            print("you lost a life")
            print("bob choosed scissors")
            print("you now have ", life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 3 and computer_choice == 1:
            print("You lose")
            life = life - 1
            print("you lost a life")
            print("bob choosed rock")
            print("you now have ", life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 3 and computer_choice == 2:
            print("You win")
            comp_life = comp_life - 1
            print ("computer lost a life")
            print("bob choosed paper")
            print ("computer now have ", comp_life, " lives")
        elif user_choice == 3 and computer_choice == 3:
            print("Draw")
        elif user_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 3:
            print("You win")
            comp_life = comp_life - 1
            print("computer lost a life")
            print("bob choosed scissors")
            print ("computer now have ", comp_life, " lives")
        if life < 1:
            print("You lose")
            exit()
        elif comp_life < 1:
            print("You win")
            exit()
    rock_paper_scissors()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few things, dont define the function in the while loop, only call it there. And instead of writing life = life - 1 use life -= 1. Try to describe your problem more accuratly

Comment: The issue is that you are calling the entire `rock_paper_scissors` function each loop which resets the life counter to 3 at the beginning of running the function. Your `if` statements are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your function. Instead of using `while True`, just use the recursive function, it will make sense to run a function that is called many times.

```py
import random

print("welcome. I am bob the AI.\nWe will play rock paper scissors. This is how we play rock paper           scissors\nRock beat scissors\nScissors beat paper\nPaper beat paper rock\n")
print("you and bob have three lives if you lose all lives the game will be over, if computer lose all lives you will win \n\n")

def rock_paper_scissors(list_name, life, comp_life):
    print("1 = rock\n2 = paper\n3 =scissors\nEnter")
    user_choice = int(input("1, 2, 3\n"))
    if user_choice > 3 or user_choice < 1:
        print("Invalid choice")
        rock_paper_scissors(list_name, life, comp_life)
    name = list_name[user_choice - 1]
    print("You choosed ", name)
    print("Bob's turn")
    computer_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Draw")
    elif (user_choice == 1 and computer_choice == 3) or (user_choice > computer_choice):
        print("You win")
        comp_life -= 1
        print("computer lost a life")
        print("bob choosed", list_name[computer_choice - 1])
        print("computer now have ", comp_life, " lives")
    else:
        print("You lose")
        life -= 1
        print("you lost a life")
        print("bob choosed", list_name[computer_choice - 1])
        print("you now have ", life, " lives")
    print(f"=== You ({life}) vs Bob ({comp_life}) ===")
    if life < 1:
        print("You lose")
        exit()
    elif comp_life < 1:
        print("You win")
        exit()
    else:
        rock_paper_scissors(list_name, life, comp_life)

list_name = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
life = 3
comp_life = 3
rock_paper_scissors(list_name, life, comp_life)
```

Example output:

```
welcome. I am bob the AI.
We will play rock paper scissors. This is how we play rock paper           scissors
Rock beat scissors
Scissors beat paper
Paper beat paper rock

you and bob have three lives if you lose all lives the game will be over, if computer lose all lives you will win       


1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
1
You choosed  rock
Bob's turn
Draw
=== You (3) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
2
You choosed  paper
Bob's turn
Draw
=== You (3) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
3
You choosed  scissors
Bob's turn
You lose
you lost a life
bob choosed rock
you now have  2  lives
=== You (2) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
2
You choosed  paper
Bob's turn
Draw
=== You (2) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
1
You choosed  rock
Bob's turn
Draw
=== You (2) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
2
You choosed  paper
Bob's turn
You lose
you lost a life
bob choosed rock
you now have  1  lives
=== You (1) vs Bob (3) ===
1 = rock
2 = paper
3 =scissors
Enter
1, 2, 3
3
You choosed  scissors
Bob's turn
You lose
you lost a life
bob choosed paper
you now have  0  lives
=== You (0) vs Bob (3) ===
You lose
```

Comment: Recursion is a very wrong way to code this.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was primarily that you were resetting the counter each iteration of the loop, but there are many things that could be improved.

Here is another implementation for you to consider, with the following features:

- Uses a dictionary for choices for consistency.
- Uses separate recursive function for getting user input.
- Validates the input.
- Allows any number of starting lives.
- Should be pretty easy to follow.

```py
import random

CHOICES = {1: "rock", 2: "paper", 3: "scissors"}


def get_choice() -> int:
    choices_str = ", ".join([f"{k} for {v}" for k, v in CHOICES.items()])
    choice = input(f"Enter {choices_str}: ")
    if choice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        choice = get_choice()
    return int(choice)


def game(lives: int) -> bool:
    """Given starting lives play with computer and return bool indicating win."""
    comp_lives = lives
    player_lives = lives
    while comp_lives > 0 and player_lives > 0:
        print(f"Your lives: {player_lives}, Computer lives: {comp_lives}")
        player_choice = get_choice()
        print(f"You chose {CHOICES[player_choice]}.")
        comp_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(f"Computer chose {CHOICES[comp_choice]}.")
        if comp_choice == player_choice:  # draw
            continue  # draw
        if comp_choice in [player_choice + 1, player_choice - 2]:  # computer win
            player_lives -= 1
            continue
        if player_choice in [comp_choice + 1, player_choice - 2]:  # player win
            comp_lives -= 1
    if comp_lives > 0:
        print("Computer wins; you suck.")
        return False
    print("You win!")
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = game(3)
```

Here is a sample interaction:

```
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 3
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose paper.
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 3
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose paper.
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 3
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose rock.
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 2
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose rock.
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 1
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose paper.
Your lives: 3, Computer lives: 1
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 3
You chose scissors.
Computer chose rock.
Your lives: 2, Computer lives: 1
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 4
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 3
You chose scissors.
Computer chose rock.
Your lives: 1, Computer lives: 1
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose paper.
Your lives: 1, Computer lives: 1
Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors: 2
You chose paper.
Computer chose rock.
You win!
```

---

As an aside, I completely understand if this is removed as "not an answer", but I still hope it is helpful.